# Issue with insert and select multiple rows in Sqlite using phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am new to Sqlite and java script. I am getting struck with inserting and selecting multiple rows in sqlite database. Can any one help me to that how can I insert and select multiple rows ? my code is as follows,

```
var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Demo", -1);
db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test_table');
    tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test_table (id integer primary key, data text, data_num integer)');
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO test_table (data, data_num) VALUES (?,?)", ["test", 100], function(tx, res) {
        console.log("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- probably 1"); // check #18/#38 is fixed
        alert("insertId: " + res.insertId + " -- should be valid");
        db.transaction(function(tx) {
            tx.executeSql("SELECT data_num from test_table;", [], function(tx, res) {
                console.log("res.rows.length: " + res.rows.length + " -- should be 1");
                alert("res.rows.item(0).data_num: " + res.rows.item(i).data_num + " -- should be 100");
            });
        });
    }, function(e) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + e.message);
    });
});
```

And How can i insert values from one java script function and how can i retrieve values from another function is it possible? if yes can anyone suggest some good tutorials or explain the same.

Comment: You need to clean up that code and tell us what the problem is, or we can't help you.

Comment: I have cleaned up my code, can you please help me

Comment: No you haven't, you just reduced the indentation of the entire thing. It's very hard to tell how deeply items are nested, where functions end, or most importantly, what you are trying to do that you can't do now.